# C++ reading big file with several section

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to write a simple program in C++ that given a big file of data divided in several groups X,Y,Z, there is a Header in which there is written the the int number of the size of data that follows. This number is preceded by a string "I=", you can visual the file here  http://dpaste.com/19HQY58

I have wrote a code that reads well the first part, but for the other part the code fails reading... here is the code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <string>
# include <sstream>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cmath>
# include <vector>
# include <exception>
# include <algorithm>
# include <cstring>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using namespace std;

//--- Function prototipes 


void readData(vector<vector<vector<double>>>*, string& , int&);


//---

int main(int args, char* argv[]){

  string time,root ;    
  string filename = "stangle.000000000.dat" 
  int N;    

       
  vector<vector<vector<double>>>* ptrData ;
                 
  ptrData = new vector<vector<vector<double>>>(10); 
     
  readData(ptrData, filename, N);

           
  return 0;
}


//---
//
   
void readData( vector<vector<vector<double>>>* data,  string& file, int& size){
      unsigned int header = 3;
      string tmp, row ;

      ifstream inputFile;
      
      cout << file << endl;
      try
      {
            inputFile.open(file, ios::in);
      }
      catch(...) 
      {
            cerr << "Error occurred opening file " << file << " program terminate!" << endl;
            exit(1);
      }
      
      int indx=0;
                 
    int k=0;
      
    while(getline(inputFile,row) && (k <= 1)){
     if(k==0)
      while( k++ <= header-1 && getline(inputFile,row)){ 
            istringstream elem(row);
            if(k == header ){
                  while(elem >> tmp){
                             if(strcmp(tmp.c_str(),"I=" )== 0){
                               elem >> tmp ; 
                               size = atoi(tmp.c_str());
                             }
                  }
           }
     }
     else
     {
       int w = 0 ;
       while( w++ <= header-1 && getline(inputFile,row)){ 
            istringstream elem(row);
            if(w == header-1 ){
                  while(elem >> tmp){
                             if(strcmp(tmp.c_str(),"I=" )== 0){
                               elem >> tmp ; 
                               size = atoi(tmp.c_str());
                             }
                  }
           }
       }
      }

      cout << "size = " << size << endl;
      
      k=0;
      data->resize(size*3) ;
      data->at(k).resize(size*3) ;
      

      for(int i=0; i<size; i++)                // resize vector ! 
                  data->at(k)[i].resize(3) ;
      
      int j=0;
      while(getline(inputFile,row) && j < size){
            istringstream elem(row);
            for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
                  elem >> data->at(k)[j].at(i); 
            elem >> tmp ;                    // 4th columns to skip
            j++;
      }
      
        
      k++ ;
   }   
}
```

could somebody help me? thank you

here an example of the sample

```
VARIABLES= "X","Y","Z","T" 
 
 
ZONE I=    10  F=POINT  T="time=      0.0000000000 " 
  0.386493318E-01  0.128555549E-01  0.340086408E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.383133255E-01  0.138539430E-01  0.340525173E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.382215269E-01  0.148848109E-01  0.340615511E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.377206728E-01  0.157320835E-01  0.342985764E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.370856710E-01  0.163890962E-01  0.346758589E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.365753844E-01  0.170070678E-01  0.349843502E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.362384841E-01  0.179224834E-01  0.353175104E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.362287983E-01  0.188916922E-01  0.356959850E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.361620262E-01  0.199434906E-01  0.359359272E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.361897759E-01  0.210271589E-01  0.360902399E-01  0.312500005E-02
 
 
ZONE I=     6  F=POINT  T="time=      0.0000000000 " 
  0.435949154E-01  0.254055243E-01 -0.491932891E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.434608348E-01  0.254306290E-01 -0.482175574E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.432049297E-01  0.259031206E-01 -0.474165194E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.427575074E-01  0.264129750E-01 -0.467625186E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.420416631E-01  0.268291328E-01 -0.463280752E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.411394201E-01  0.266988464E-01 -0.461011454E-01  0.312500005E-02


 
 
ZONE I=     4  F=POINT  T="time=      0.0000000000 " 
  0.435949154E-01  0.254055243E-01 -0.491932891E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.434608348E-01  0.254306290E-01 -0.482175574E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.432049297E-01  0.259031206E-01 -0.474165194E-01  0.312500005E-02
  0.427575074E-01  0.264129750E-01 -0.467625186E-01  0.312500005E-02`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails reading"? Have you tried to step through your code, line by line, in a debugger to see what really happens?

Comment: i doubt that someone who knows the answer will wait for an hour just to make you sweat. All answers here are as soon as possible

Comment: 1.  Please [edit] your question to include a simple sample file actually *in* the question.  2.  Your link to the sample file is broken.

Comment: _help me a soon as possible_ are you more important than the others?

Comment: sorry for unappropriate sentence asap ! really ! I have coorect the link so the sample is available now

Comment: ... and please try to minimize your sample code as much as possible.  Do you really need to populate your vector of vectors?, or could you just read the data and discard it?  Congratulations for supplying complete code, but we need **minimal** too.

Comment: ok I have minimalized it ! (i guess) :)

Comment: You most likely do not need to allocate your vector with new and you should pass it by reference once you remove that, and you can also remove the initial size since you resize it later.. The filename doesn't change, pass that by const reference. Don't really need the size parameter, you can calculate that from the vector size. Otherwise you've got a curious mix of C and C++ that's kind of hard to follow. You might consider breaking the different section reads into their own functions. It's not really clear what first and other parts are. What exactly isn't reading correctly?

Comment: why dont neeed the size ? i need the size for reading just the block and not over ... so i need ! and i need to stored this file in a matrix contained in a matrix container ... this is the reason of vector<vector<vector>> ... the mix between c and c++ is because i din't know a similar function for comparing the string and individuates "I="  with which i can read the integer corresponding to the size!

Comment: i don't get the size! after read it i goes foward reading and retaining tha data

Comment: This is how I might do it. It assumes the file is perfect so you'd need to add more error checking and such, but break the problem down into smaller chunks and it's easier to make each piece work. https://ideone.com/ZpD0LL

Comment: but in this way it reads only the first block !

Comment: I don't understand.  Why are you converting `std::string` to C-Style string to use `strcmp`?  Why not use `operator==` directly?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a redesign of your program.

Your input file contains blocks of records.  So, design it that way.

```
struct Record
{
  double m_values[4]; // These could be itemized if you know their purpose
};

struct Block
{
  std::string m_f;
  double      m_time;
  std::vector<Record> m_records;
};
```

The next step would be to overload `operator>>` in each class to read in the data members.

```
struct Record
{
  //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.m_values[0];
  input >> r.m_values[1];
  input >> r.m_values[2];
  input >> r.m_values[3];
  return input;
}

struct Block
{
  //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Block& b);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Block& b)
{
  std::string text;
  while (std::getline(input, text))
  {
    if (text.empty()) continue;
    static const char zone_key_text[] = "ZONE I=";
    std::string::size_type position = text.find(zone_key_text);
    if (position != 0) continue;
    std::istringstream text_stream(text.substr(sizeof(zone_key_text) - 1));
    int record_quantity = 0;
    text_stream >> record_quantity;
    // Parse remaining fields
    Record r;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
    {
      input >> r;
      m_records.push_back(r);
    }
    //...
}
```

The `ZONE I=` contains the number of records.  The quantity of records varies, which is a good indicator to use `std::vector` for the records.

Reading of the file then becomes:

```
std::string variables;
std::getline(inputFile, variables);
std::vector<Block> database;
Block b;
while (inputFile >> b)
{
  database.push_back(b);
}
```

You probably want to parse the variables text line, then use a `std::map<char, Block>` to associate a variable with the block of data.